# theres anyone know open source SMS app for android?

Tags: android, sms

i need an SMS app that i can change .

SGS2 or/and NOKIA S40 compatible please.

anyone know ?

Comment: While the phrasing is poor, a request for an open source solution as a starting point for customization seems entirely on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out the Android Open Source Project's MMS app.](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Mms.git;a=summary)

Comment: Question is if that is an SDK compliant app, or one that uses private functionality and so is hard to build except as part of a full platform build.

Comment: It is "SDK compliant"; doesn't use any hacks.